# Rails 4 RoutingError: No Route Matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working through a small exercise while learning Rails 4, but running into a routing error while trying to update an object.  I keep getting an error message:  **No route matches [POST] "/movies/1/edit"** but can't see where my code is not correct:

my movies_controller.rb

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  def show
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.create(movie_params)

    if @movie.save 
        redirect_to "/movies/#{@movie.id}", :notice => "Your movie was saved!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])

    if @movie.update_attributes(params[:movie])
        redirect_to "/movies"
    else
        render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy

  end


  private

  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:name, :genre, :year)
  end
end
```

Here's my edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Now Editing:</h1>

<h3><%= @movie.name %></h3>

<%= form_for @movie.name do |f| %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<br>
<%= f.label :genre %>
<%= f.text_field :genre %>
<br>
<%= f.label :year %>
<%= f.number_field :year %>
<br>
<%= f.submit "Update" %>
```

and the routes.rb file:

```
MovieApp::Application.routes.draw do

  get "movies"             => "movies#index"
  post "movies"            => "movies#create"
  get "movies/new"         => "movies#new"
  get "movies/:id"         => "movies#show"
  get "movies/:id/edit"    => "movies#edit"
  put "movies/:id"         => "movies#update"

end
```

last, here's the output from running `rake routes`:

```
    Prefix Verb URI Pattern                Controller#Action
    movies GET  /movies(.:format)          movies#index
           POST /movies(.:format)          movies#create
movies_new GET  /movies/new(.:format)      movies#new
           GET  /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#show
           GET  /movies/:id/edit(.:format) movies#edit
           PUT  /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#update
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`form_for @movie.name` should be `form_for @movie`. I can't tell what's going on, but I suspect this is somehow giving you a `<form action="">`.

Comment: that would be my guess as well, and the blank action would post back to the current_url which is the edit path

Comment: Thanks @meager, but I am now getting a ``NoMethodError in Movies#edit: undefined method `movie_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff4cb263e38>:0x007ff4c99f6300>``?

Comment: You haven't named your routes. You need to use either use `get "movies" => "movies#index", as: "movies"`, or, the correct thing, just throw out all your routes and just use `resources :movies`.

Comment: Not naming the routes was the problem, @meager, thanks.  I knew I could just throw in ``resources :movies`` into my ``routes.rb`` file, but I wanted to do it manually to understand how routing worked.  Thanks again~

Answer (score 2):

Your error message shows that you are sending a post request to the edit url.

> No route matches [POST] "/movies/1/edit"

Whereas in the route you have specified a get request.

> get "movies/:id/edit"    => "movies#edit"

I believe that is somehow causing the problem and so you could change the request to post.

```
post "movies/:id/edit"    => "movies#edit"
```

Comment: that isn't the real problem.  you are *supposed* to 'GET' The edit form, and the POST/PUT it back the resource to make the changes. Changing edit to a POST breaks that. and isn't the correct thing to do.

Comment: His routes are fine, he definitely should *not* be modifying his routes to accept the wrong method. This is just going to give him another bug, and his route certainly will never reach `movies#update` where it needs to reach.

Answer (score 1):

in index file if you are using

```
button_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path(movie)
```

change it to

```
link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path(movie)
```

because button send it as `POST` but the link will send it as `GET`.